# Bootstrap Hamburger Icon not aligning with Navbar-Brand

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a website using bootstrap and while using the navbar component, I'm facing an issue where in when the screen shrinks to the breakpoint I've set (which is `lg`) the hamburger icon's alignment gets disrupted as seen below.

Can someone please let me know why this is happening and what is the best way to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Johns's Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Linking custom CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  <!-- Linking Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="navbar-brand fw-bold">John Doe</span>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ToggleMenu" aria-controls="ToggleMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="ToggleMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Education</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Bootstrap Javascript files-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm also attaching a picture of the issue:
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Why don't you follow the [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)? They already have responsive example.

Comment: Hey @vee yes the document works fine I just wanted to know why such an issue occurs. Thanks

Comment: Because you wrap `navbar-brand` within `container` but not `navbar-toggler`. You can check this yourself by carefully read it or use a tool like **WinMerge** or comparer tools to compare the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you put your button outside of `container`

```
<div class="container">
      <span class="navbar-brand fw-bold">John Doe</span>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ToggleMenu" aria-controls="ToggleMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
```

It needs to be like this

```
<div class="container">
      <span class="navbar-brand fw-bold">John Doe</span>
<button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ToggleMenu" aria-controls="ToggleMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    </div>
```

You can try this fix

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Johns's Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Linking custom CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  <!-- Linking Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="navbar-brand fw-bold">John Doe</span>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Education</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Bootstrap Javascript files-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```